# pip Virtualenv vs. directory in project

Tags: python, pip, virtualenv

Why does `pip` need to use virtual environments to isolate packages per-project, instead of just installing them in a default directory in the project? This seems like added complexity without benefit.

NPM, for example, installs packages in the `<project_root>\node_modules` by default. No virtual environment necessary, and packages are still installed in a project-independent way.

**Edit:** To be clear, I'm interested in the *practical* advantages to pip's use of virtual environments over package management systems like NPM, Nuget, and Webpack, which all use directories in the project. Otherwise, if this is just a limitation of Python's modules system, then I'd be interested to know that too.

Comment: Python packaging ecosystem is horrible. It's hard to do something with it, because it's quite old. But virtualenv is quite a good workaround which makes installing packages much more pleasure. Recently more high level tools have become to appear, which combine pip and virtualenv (for example `poetry`)

Answer (score 1):

Because Python's module system doesn't work that way.  If pip were to install, say, `requests` by just downloading it to a `python_modules` directory, that wouldn't be enough to for `import requests` to work; it would have to be `import python_modules.requests`, but then we'd still have problems whenever `requests` tried to import one of its dependencies, as that would need `python_modules` prepended, too, and it'd just be a big mess.  The solution that virtual environments use is to modify the `PYTHONPATH` environment variable to include `python_modules`, plus some extra stuff to take care of executable scripts and not importing packages from outside the virtualenv.

Comment: Thanks @jwodder! So virtual environments are accommodating Python's module system.

Is there a practical advantage to the module system working this way over the Node example I mentioned?

Comment: @JoshNoe: I'm not familiar enough with how Node's module system works to answer that.

Answer (score 0):

I think maybe you don't know what a virtual environment actually is.

If you were to put some module in a project-specific directory, like `myproj/modules`, then you would have to add `myproj/modules` to the search path that Python uses so that you module can be found. One way to do that is to define or modify the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`. Any directories listed in that variable will be searched for modules, in addition to some hard-coded set of directories.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=./myproj/modules
```

However, that's really all a virtual environment is. The directory contains the desired version of Python, along with whatever modules you want to use. The `activate` script you run to "enable" a virtual environment does little more than set the value of `PATH` and `PYTHONPATH` so that anytime you run `python`, both the correct version is used and your project-specific set of modules is used in place of any global library.

Comment: virtualenv modify `PATH` but not `PYTHONPATH`. Also virtualenv disable importing from global `site-packages` which no manipulations with `PYTHONPATH` could do.

Comment: Thanks @chepner! I now understand the technical reasons for virtual environments. I was more interested if this was a conscious design choice. It appears that no, virtual environments are just a workaround for Python's module system which doesn't support per-project package management out of the box. Is this correct?